# organisation chart in flex

Tags: apache-flex

how to create organisation chart in flex using xml

Answer (score 1):

The guys over at yWorks offer some good looking visulisation charts that might be just what you're looking for. These components can be easily used with Flex so that you can do other manipulations with the data.

Here's one I found that fits in with an Organisation Chart flow:

http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesflex_about.html?gclid=CLT5wriG750CFeZr4wodz1OoMg

and here's a demo from their site of a company chart being fed by an XML document:

http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-flex/demo/orgchartdemo/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Visualizer component from KapLab (http://lab.kapit.fr/display/visualizer/Visualizer). Checkout their demos. An Awesome components with a lot of Graph Layouts (including Organization charts layout) and with high flexibility level, and Freeeeeeeeeeee. Hope it helps.